# Sorting the List in Javascript

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, javascript-debugging

```
@api weekdaySelectionData=[];

The below is coming through data table, but  I just want to sort the final list:

weekdaySelectionData=[{"Day__c":"Tue","Morning__c":true,"Afternoon__c":false,"Evening__c":false},{"Day__c":"Mon","Morning__c":true,"Afternoon__c":false,"Evening__c":false},{"Day__c":"Thurs","Morning__c":true,"Afternoon__c":false,"Evening__c":false}]
```

How to sort this list? I would like to have Mon as on 1st index, then tue then thurs.

PLease help..Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: You can write your own custom sorting logic using the `.sort()` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort. In case you are querying the records consider adding an `Order By` clause to the SOQL to sort it out at the Apex side itself

Comment: could you please share the code for the above, I mean it is not from SOQL. It is taking user input only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a custom sort method like this.

```
const indexes = {
    Mon: { index: 1 },
    Tue: { index: 2 },
    Wed: { index: 3 },
    Thurs: { index: 4 },
    Fri: { index: 5 },
    Sat: { index: 6 },
    Sun: { index: 7 }
};
export default class YourComponentName extends LightningElement {

    //... other code

    weekdaySelectionData = [
        {
            Day__c: "Tue",
            Morning__c: true,
            Afternoon__c: false,
            Evening__c: false
        },
        {
            Day__c: "Mon",
            Morning__c: true,
            Afternoon__c: false,
            Evening__c: false
        },
        {
            Day__c: "Thurs",
            Morning__c: true,
            Afternoon__c: false,
            Evening__c: false
        }
    ];

    get sortedData() {
        return this.weekdaySelectionData.sort((a, b) => {
            let dayA = indexes[a.Day__c].index;
            let dayB = indexes[b.Day__c].index;
            return dayA - dayB;
        });
    }
}
```

Just use or modify the `sortedData` to get the sorted elements. Also if you want to change the order or names of days the modify the `indexes` global constant.
**Please note that the keys are case `SeNsiTIVe`**

[Here is the playground for this example](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/uMdrleOPmbVjTFgQQUrk/src/app.js)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code but I am not getting the same output.. i think the message is not getting called.

Comment: Sorry just now edited the API name. It was wrongly typed.. Thanks a ton for your help. Really greatful to you :) thanks alot.

Comment: @Rahul - The 'sortedData()' can further be reduced to just a single line with ES6 notations  as `return this.weekdaySelectionData.sort((a, b) => indexes[a.Day__c].index - indexes[b.Day__c].index);`

Comment: @SarojBera great, thanks!